# Different sys.path between pypy and normal python

Tags: python, pypy

I'm trying to use `pypy` compiler to run my python code but the `sys.path` for pypy is different from normal python compiler so when I tried to import default modules such as

```
import pygame
```

it fails in pypy, stating that the module is not found, while it works correctly with the normal python command. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13635272/846892

Comment: As it is said in the related question, `pygame` is (was?) not compatible with `pypy`. More generally, concerning the "module not found" error, maybe you could show in your question both your `pypy` and `CPython` `sys.path` in order to compare them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're expecting any module installed for CPython to work with PyPy out of the box.  That's not the case.  It's the same when you upgrade from CPython 2.6 to CPython 2.7: the modules you have already installed for 2.6 are not automatically available for 2.7, and must be re-installed.  Similarly, you must re-install the modules for PyPy.

This said, the standard pygame doesn't work too well with PyPy, but stay tuned; it seems someone is working on a version of pygame based on cffi, which should work very well with PyPy.