# Using MySQLdb module with Pypy compiler

Tags: python, mysql-python, pypy

I'm trying Pypy compiler to see if I can speed up my code. Nevertheless, I'm having troubles with MySQLdb module, which Pypy is unable to find.

I have read that MySQLdb 1.2.4 should work fine with Pypy, so I upgraded the module, and I tested that it is the right version with CPython compiler:

```
import MySQLdb
MySQLdb.__version__
>> '1.2.4'
```

But when using Pypy, I'm getting:

```
Python 2.7.2 (1.9+dfsg-1, Jun 19 2012, 23:23:45)
[PyPy 1.9.0 with GCC 4.7.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``-FIRST they ignore you, then they
laugh at you, then they fight you, then you win.-''
>>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Any help? I'm running over Ubuntu 13.04 and using Pypy which came into the Canonical repositories.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187959/different-sys-path-between-pypy-and-normal-python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MySQLdb` is mostly written in C which pypy can't use directly. You'd need to [patch and recompile](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/mysql-python) it.

The easier solution would be to use a pure python mysql connector library, like [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) or [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python)

pymysql can even be used as dropin replacement for MySQLdb, all you need to do add:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

or put this in a module `MySQLdb.py`, after that code which imports `MySQLdb` should work normally.

Comment: Is pymysql much slower than MySQLdb? Without pypy I'm getting twice as much processing time

Comment: it should be way better on pypy then on cpython, but i haven't done any benchmarks. usually the bottleneck is the database performance anyway.

Comment: OK, I've done som very simple test with a bunch of inserts, queries and deletes on a test table. cpython2.7.4+MySQLdb: `50 loops, best of 3: 80 msec per loop`, pypy1.9.0+pymysql: `50 loops, best of 3: 89.7 msec per loop` - so for this testcase pypy+pymysql was about 12% slower - but the result may not really be representative for mor complex usecases.

Comment: Yeah without pypy pymysql is very slow. I am using oursql and tried to convert to pymysql for pypy compatibility but now processing is way too high.