# Is there an event handling option to minimize and maximize screen in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, event-handling

Is there any event handler to minimize or maximize screen like there is to quit screen?

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

Pygame adds `pygame.ACTIVEEVENT`s to the event queue when the window is minimized/iconified or maximized. You can check `if event.gain == 1 and event.state == 6:` and `if event.gain == 0 and event.state == 6:` to see if the window was maximized or minimized. The only problem is that `event.gain == 1 and event.state == 6` is also `True` when the window gains input focus.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_i:
                pg.display.iconify()
        elif event.type == pg.ACTIVEEVENT:
            if event.gain == 1 and event.state == 6:
                print('maximized')
            elif event.gain == 0 and event.state == 6:
                print('minimized')

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

If you want to minimize/iconify the window with a key press, you can call [`pygame.display.iconify()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.iconify).